# Ramda - Partition by index

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

How can I achieve a `partition` by `index` using [RamdaJS](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#uncurryN)?

```js
/*
 * @param {number} index
 * @param {[]} list

 * @returns {[found, rest[]]} - array whose index 0 has the found element 
 * * and index 1 has the rest of the given list
*/
const partitionByIndex = (index, list) => {};
```

```js
// this is what I got so far, but I really think it is too verbose

export const partitionByIndex = R.curry((i, cards) => R.pipe(
  R.partition(R.equals(R.nth(i, cards))),
  ([found, rest]) => [R.head(found), rest],
)(cards));

const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const index = 1;

const [found, rest] = partitionByIndex(index, list);

console.log({ found, rest });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly simple point-free solution is

```
const partitionByIndex = converge(pair, [compose(of, nth), flip(remove)(1)])

partitionByIndex(2, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) //=> [['c'], ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']]
```

And that `flip` makes me realize that the arguments to `remove` are probably mis-ordered.

### Update

Yogi pointed out that the desired response might be `['c', ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']]` rather than the result above: `[['c'], ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']]`.  And if that's the case, this code can become simpler:

```
const partitionByIndex = converge(pair, [nth, flip(remove)(1)])

partitionByIndex(2, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) //=> ['c', ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']]
```

Comment: As they don't need the found value to be a list, wouldn't `converge(pair, [nth, flip(remove)(1)])` be enough?

Comment: @Yoshi: Perhaps.  I may not have interpreted the question properly.  That was actually my first thought.  I changed to the above because of how I think of partitions working.  But looking at the code attempt, I think you're right.  Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to this is to `R.take` and `R.drop` around the `R.nth` element, such as:

```
R.converge(R.pair, [R.nth, (n, xs) => R.concat(R.take(n, xs), R.drop(n + 1, xs))])
```

Or without Ramda:

```
(n, xs) => [xs[n], xs.slice(0, n).concat(xs.slice(n + 1))]
```